# Can I bring a person with me while getting landing current if they're a licensed, current pilot?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency

It's been over 90 days since I've been flying, but I have a biennial flight review coming up pretty soon and would like to prep for it.

The regulations regarding this seem to be extremely vague, but is it legal for me to fly around, do my landings, log PIC time, and such with another licensed, current pilot in the plane with me?

Answer (score 16):

As long as  you are not the legal pilot in command you can do what you want.  This means the other pilot has to be willing to act as the legal pilot in command on this flight.

> [61.57](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=754abc363b0a3df897df6f956dde81f9&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_157&rgn=div8)(a) General experience.
>
> (1) Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may
>   act as a **pilot in command** of an aircraft **carrying passengers** or of an
>   aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember unless
>   that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within
>   the preceding 90 days, and—
>
> (i) The person acted as the sole manipulator of the flight controls;

The regulation is clearly required of the legal pilot in command.  If your current passenger is willing to act and take responsibility for your flying as the legal pilot in command then it is allowable.

Unfortunately, the other pilot is taking all the responsibility and gets none of the credit as they, under an airplane certificated for single pilot operations, cannot log any PIC time while you are getting current.

From [LOGGING PILOT IN COMMAND TIME (FAA)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/sdl/local_more/avsafety_program/media/LOGGING%20PILOT-IN-COMMAND%20TIME.pdf):

> However, two pilots may not simultaneously log PIC when one pilot is
>   sole manipulator of the controls and the other is acting as
>   pilot-in-command if the regulations governing the flight do not
>   require more than one pilot.

---

If the other pilot is a CFI and it is a training flight then no one has to be landing current as there are no passengers.  See the [Kortokrax interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/data/interps/2006/kortokrax%20-%20(2006)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf).

Relevant excerpt:

> We agree that, for purposes of section 61.57(b), an authorized
>   instructor providing instruction in an aircraft is not considered a
>   passenger with respect to the person receiving instruction, even where
>   the person receiving the instruction is acting as PIC. (The instructor
>   must be current, qualified to instruct, and hold a category, class and
>   type rating in the aircraft, if a class and type rating is required.)
>   The instructor is not a passenger because he is present specifically
>   to train the person receiving instruction. Neither is the person
>   receiving instruction a passenger with respect to the instructor. This
>   training may take place, even though neither pilot has met the
>   61.57(b) requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is true. It might be worth getting a FSDO interpretation, but it goes against everything I've understood about acting/logging PIC.

Comment: @egid Remember that to the FAA, acting as PIC and logging PIC are completely different things.

Comment: @egid What do you disagree with?  This is actually pretty clear.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer. The regs clearly say no one else, and no property either, during the flights where the pilot wants to regain currency.

Comment: @JuanJimenez The regulations say that the *pilot in command* must be current if there are any passengers. Under the proposed scenario, the pilot in command is current. So, that means it's okay.

Comment: @TannerSwett That is not correct. The desired result is for a pilot who cannot act as PIC to regain currency. For that to happen the pilot who wants to achieve that must be the PIC and may not be in the airplane with anyone else, or with any property. It's crystal clear, not legal to claim currency if there is another pilot in the plane with you.

Comment: @JuanJimenez I don't think that's correct, and I have another question for you, but the comments on this answer aren't the place to talk about this. Can you please create an answer post explaining your point?

Comment: The answer to why your point is incorrect is spelled out in 61.57(2). It's posted verbatim in the first answer below. To achieve currency, there can be no persons or property in the aircraft other than the pilot who wants to achieve currency. This doesn't need any further explanation.

Comment: @JuanJimenez.  You are confusing logging PIC time with acting as pilot in command.  You don’t have to be the legal pilot in command to regain landing currency.

Comment: @wbeard52 You are reaching for something that is not there. If the FAR unequivocably states that **there can be no other persons on the aircraft**, the pilot **has** to be the PIC. If you can find some magic way that someone can be flying solo and not be PIC, let us know.

Comment: @JuanJimenez 61.57(a)(2) “a person **may** act as a pilot in command of an aircraft under day VFR or day IFR, provided no persons or property are carried on board the aircraft.  If the person getting landing current is the legal pilot in command then no other people can be on board.  If another is the legal pilot in command than they can be on board.  Notice the word may instead of must.  Regs are very clear in this matter.

Comment: @wbeard52 If the the other person is the legal pilot, you cannot claim you have become current. You cannot selectively take things out of the regs to make a point. "For the purpose of meeting the requirements of paragraph (a)(1) of this section..." I'm done arguing this with you. You think you're right? Try it and see what the FAA thinks about that. Or better yet, try it, have that pilot get into an accident and see what the insurance thinks about your interpretation. Good luck with that.

Comment: @JuanJimenez.  Did you not read the legal interpretation listed in the answer.  That is the FAA saying what I’m arguing.  No reason to be rude, we are all here to learn.  There are holes in your understanding though.  Feel free to ask the FAA for an interpretation affirming this answer.

Comment: @wbeard52 Have you read it yourself? It *only* references 61.57(b), which has nothing to do with the landings currency referenced in 61.57(a), the subject of this question. My understanding of this is watertight. I suggest you read it again, carefully this time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's that ambiguous. The kicker in your requirementsis the "log PIC time" part...

[CFR 61.57](http://flightphysical.com/part61/currency/a.htm)

> (a) General experience.
>
> (1) Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, **no person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft carrying passengers** or of an aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember unless that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days, and—
>
> (i) **The person acted as the sole manipulator of the flight controls**;

And this section:

> (2) For the purpose of meeting the requirements of paragraph (a)(1) of this section, a person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft under day VFR or day IFR, **provided no persons or property are carried on board the aircraft**, other than those necessary for the conduct of the flight.

So I interpret that as no passengers. If the other pilot is a CFI and giving instruction, then that would count but if they are just going for a ride, no its not "legal". The take offs and landings have to be done either solo, not as PIC, or under instruction.

The other person may be a pilot, but unless they are performing pilot duties they are a passenger like any non pilot rated passenger. By the way,  the PIC does not have to sit on the left, you can still occupy the left seat as long as your pilot friend accepts PIC responsibilities as you complete your currency then you can resume being PIC.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with this interpretation. The way I conclude, from your highlighted statements, is (1) the person trying to get current has to be the sole manipulator of the controls, AND (2) the other pilot (who is current) acting as PIC.

Comment: Don't you need to be certified in some way to fly from the right hand seat? If I'm correct that means the average pilot cannot act as PIC from the right (unless there is some odd loophole that says the PIC doesn't have to actually be able to fly the thing).

Comment: @Ben -- that's worthy of asking a new question

Comment: @kevin that is correct. The PIC doesn't have to be the one manipulating the controls. See http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/Learn-to-Fly/Aviation-Subject-Report-Logging-Pilot-in-Command-PIC-Time

Comment: @Ben No,  there is no regulation that says you need special training to fly right seat. You can sit wherever you like as long as you can safely manipulate the controls.

Comment: It's fine to fly from the right seat. But some older bonanzas have a "throw over" control yoke, which I wouldn't act PIC from the right seat in unless I also had the yoke

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I believe that [wbeard52's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/27067/62) is correct: [61.57](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&r=SECTION&n=14y2.0.1.1.2.1.1.36) says the *acting PIC* must be current to carry passengers; it doesn't say that the person *at the controls* must be current.

If you consider AOPA to be an authoritative source, their [February 2011 *Legal Briefing* column](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2011/february/flight-training-magazine/legal-briefing) discussed exactly this question:

> Q: I’m out of currency to take passengers in my Cessna 172. When I go
>   flying to do my three bounces, I would prefer to have someone with me
>   for an extra set of eyes and ears. Does it have to be a CFI or can it
>   be a private pilot, as long as he or she is current?
>
> A: [...] if the private pilot is current and is willing and qualified
>   to act as PIC of the aircraft, that pilot may be on board the aircraft
>   as PIC and you could be the sole manipulator of the controls in
>   getting your three bounces. I would make sure that both of you
>   understand your roles in the aircraft before taking off, to avoid any
>   misunderstandings.