# Do I need to be acting PIC when doing takeoffs and landings for my 90-day currency?

Tags: faa-regulations

The 90-day currency requirement means that to *act* as PIC of an aircraft carrying passengers you must complete the three takeoffs and landings. Does this include an aircraft where you are logging PIC time but not the acting PIC?

Could you technically then log the landings/TO's if you've blown your 90 days if you have a friend as acting PIC? The FAR also states this is required if you're operating an aircraft certified for two or more crew operations. Does this mean even without passengers, if you are a required crew member on a two crew ship, you need the 90 day currency?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27064/62)

Answer (score 4):

The regulation does not address whether or not you have to be PIC to establish currency.  It instead states that you have to do "three takeoffs and three landings as the sole manipulator of the controls" and in the "same category, class, and type (if a type rating is required)":

> Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act
>   as a pilot in command of an aircraft carrying passengers or of an
>   aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember unless
>   that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within
>   the preceding 90 days, and -
>
> (i) The person acted as the sole manipulator of the flight controls;
>   and
>
> (ii) The required takeoffs and landings were performed in an aircraft
>   of the same category, class, and type (if a type rating is required),
>   and, if the aircraft to be flown is an airplane with a tailwheel, the
>   takeoffs and landings must have been made to a full stop in an
>   airplane with a tailwheel.

Comment: Just to clarify, being the sole manipulator means you’re getting PIC time right? You’re just not acting PIC. And does the section about two crew mean regardless if you have passengers, you can act as PIC of a two crew ship unless you’re current?

Comment: @Flak Yes, but the opposite is not necessarily true.  Have a look at [this article](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/sdl/local_more/avsafety_program/media/LOGGING%20PILOT-IN-COMMAND%20TIME.pdf) from the FAA website...does a pretty good job of explaining the nuances of logging PIC time.